# Flexbox content has one pixel offset in table

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I use flexbox to adjust my alignments in a table cell:
https://jsfiddle.net/vincentle/zcgLxyd2/

```
table.qtn-header th.right-col{
    display:flex;    
    justify-content:space-between;
}
table.qtn-header th.right-col .left-item{  
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

You can see that the bottom border of the first row of the table has a "break" of one pixel.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using flexbox css with tables. Flexboxes and grids were made so that you could do some of the table-like layouts without tables (among other cold things). Use normal divs in your html.

Comment: I agree with @kumar_harsh. Don't use tables. Css `display:grid` would be the preferred method for this layout. Get started today: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the **contents** of the table cell in another `<div>` and apply `display:flex;` to the `<div>` instead. See the snippet below.

*P.S. in your example, the border breaks in Chrome but displays fine in Firefox.*

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
table.qtn-header{
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  font-size:12pt;
}

table.qtn-header td{
  padding-top:.5em;
  padding-bottom:.2em;
}

table.qtn-header th{
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size:26pt;
  border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}

table.qtn-header th.right-col .flex-wrapper {
    display:flex;    
    justify-content:space-between;
}
table.qtn-header th.right-col .left-item{  
  align-self: flex-end;
}
table.qtn-header th.right-col .right-item{
    align-self: flex-end;
}
table.qtn-header .left-col{
  width:25%;
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:1em;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
table.qtn-header .right-col{
  width:75%;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<table class="qtn-header">
  <tr>
    <th class="left-col">Devis</th>
    <th class="right-col">
      <div class="flex-wrapper">
        <div class="left-item">QTN-2018-001</div>
        <div class="rignt-item"><img  src="https://www.apitrak.com/static/images/email_cta" height="80px"/></div>
      </div>
      
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left-col">Client :</td>
    <td class="right-col">Alicia Matin, blable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left-col">Date de rédaction :</td>
    <td class="right-col">bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left-col">Date de validité</td>
    <td class="right-col">blo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed it was by adding

```
table.qtn-header tr th{
 display: flex;
}
```

to the css file.

I like to use `display: flex;` whenever possible because it is much more flexible and easier to manipulate than any other. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, This might fix your problem. You can simply select the first row of the table.

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
table.qtn-header{
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  font-size:12pt;
}

table.qtn-header td{
  padding-top:.5em;
  padding-bottom:.2em;
}

table.qtn-header th{
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size:26pt;
  /*border-bottom:1pt solid black;*/
}

table.qtn-header th.right-col{
    display:flex;    
    justify-content:space-between;
}
table.qtn-header th.right-col .left-item{  
  align-self: flex-end;
}
table.qtn-header th.right-col .right-item{
    align-self: flex-end;
}
table.qtn-header .left-col{
  width:25%;
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:1em;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
table.qtn-header .right-col{
  width:75%;
  text-align:left;
}
tr:first-child
{
  border-bottom:1pt solid #333;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<table class="qtn-header">
  <tr>
    <th class="left-col">Devis</th>
    <th class="right-col">
      <div class="left-item">QTN-2018-001</div>
      <div class="rignt-item"><img  src="https://www.apitrak.com/static/images/email_cta" height="80px"/></div>
      
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left-col">Client :</td>
    <td class="right-col">Alicia Matin, blable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left-col">Date de rédaction :</td>
    <td class="right-col">bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left-col">Date de validité</td>
    <td class="right-col">blo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```